# Why is Bootstrap moving the last column to the next row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, markup

Given the following code with no css attached to the table, nothing modifying the `row` class:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="itemGrid">
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
        <div class="col">
            <table>
                ... 4 TD columns, 4 tr rows, no content of fixed widths
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Style for .itemGrid:

```
.itemGrid{
    text-align: center;
}
```

The third column (`<div class="col-xs-1"></div>`) is being pushed to the next row as if I had specified too many columns regardless of the viewport width. Why is this?

Comment: `col` is not a valid bootstrap 3 class. You must provide a size and number of columns. eg. `col-xs-6`

Comment: I was going to post a link about how it's valid and then realized that that's a version 4 yet to be implemented... whoops. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because your second column `.col` is unspecified. Try e.g.:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="itemGrid">
    <div class="col-xs-1">test</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <table>
        ... 4 TD columns, 4 tr rows, no content of fixed widths
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. That fixes it. I had been using an alpha release documentation for version 4 without realizing it:

https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width

Comment: You're welcom, glad I could help!